# Не корректно переключается язык в мультиязычном приложение (WinForms)

Tags: c#, multilanguage

Сделал приложение которые переключается на другие языки программно на лету, но не корректно переключается, нажимаю на одну кнопку переключается на другой язык, нажимаю на другую кнопку и не переключается больше.

---

Вопросы:

1 - Как сделать переключение на двух кнопках корректно?

2 - Как сделать если на главной форме переключался язык то и при вызове `UserControl` он тоже менялся?!

3 - Как правильно сверить нужный язык и сделать переключение?!

---

Вот моя форма: ( изначальный язык Английский ( English ) но при запуске почему-то Русский язык показывается. ( Как это тоже пофиксить ? )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот сам исходный файл проекта: [MultiLanguage.rar](https://anonfile.com/X521A35dnc/MultiLanguage_rar)

---

**[UPD]**

На главной форме включил: `Localizable = true`

Сначала сделал все контролы на Английском языке, после перевёл на Русский язык, и точно так же перевёл все контролы на Русский язык.

Затем создал класс **SwitchLanguage.cs**

В нём создал метод(ы) который переключает язык:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class SwitchLanguage
{
  public static void Inizialize(string lang)
  {
    foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
    {
       LocalizeForm(frm, lang);
    }
  }

private static void LocalizeForm(Form frm, string lang)
{
  var manager = new ComponentResourceManager(frm.GetType());
  var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
  manager.ApplyResources(frm, "$this");
  ApplyResources(manager, frm.Controls);
}

private static void ApplyResources(ComponentResourceManager manager, Control.ControlCollection ctls)
{
  foreach (Control ctl in ctls)
  {
     manager.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name);
     ApplyResources(manager, ctl.Controls);
  }
}
}
```

В главной форме делаю проверку и переключаю язык:

```
public partial class MultiFrm : Form
{
  public MultiFrm() => this.InitializeComponent();

  private static string twoLetterISOLanguageName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

  // Если нажимаем на кнопку Rus то переводим на Русский язык
  private void SwitchRus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (twoLetterISOLanguageName.Equals("en", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        SwitchLanguage.Inizialize("ru");
        //this.Refresh();
    }
  }
  // Если нажимаю на кнопку Eng переводим на English язык
  private void SwitchEng_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (twoLetterISOLanguageName.Equals("ru", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        SwitchLanguage.Inizialize("en");
        //this.Refresh();
    }
  }
}
```

Собственно где я накосячил подскажите?! =)

Comment: Никому не интересно качать какие то файлы и копаться в них, подготовьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и добавьте его код прямо в вопрос.

Comment: @tym32167 А почему это "Никому"? Вы уже за всех решили? или из принципа никто не захочет это посмотреть и помочь? Я лично считаю что лучше скинуть весь проект, так хоть понятнее будет.

Comment: Почитайте правила ресурса для начала.

Comment: Я вас не хотел обидеть, давайте я поясню свою мысль. Смотрите, тут одни люди задают вопросы, другие - отвечают на вопросы. Отвечающие на вопросы делают это бесплатно и сами решают. на что отвечать, а на что не отвечать. Поэтому когда кто то опытный смотрит на вопрос, он хочет потратить как можно меньше времени на то, чтобы понять прблему. Поэтому задача автора вопроса описать проблему так, чтобы её можно было быстро понять и ответить. Для этого и нужен минимавльный пример.

Comment: Вы предлагаете сделать на 2 шага больше - чтот о скачать, распаковать, и смотреть сразу кучу кода, что является для отвечающего лишними телодвиженями, которые он мог бы не делать, если бы вы сразу показали всё, что нужно в вопросе. Я, например, обычно трачу 5-15 секунд нв то, чтобы решить, буду я чем то помогать или нет. И когда я вижу, что вопрос оформлен так, что мне неудобно его понять, я скорее всего пройду мимо.

Comment: поэтому я вам дал совет, что сделать, чтобы увеличить ваши шансы на то, что кто то вообще поглядит на ваш код. Самый простой способ - это указать код прямо в вопросе. Если вы этого не делаете по любым причинам, вы просто уменьшаете вероятность того, что вам кто то поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сколько раз (и когда) в Вашем коде присваивается значение переменной `twoLetterISOLanguageName`?

```
  //private static string twoLetterISOLanguageName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

  // Если нажимаем на кнопку Rus то переводим на Русский язык
  private void SwitchRus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        SwitchLanguage.Inizialize("ru");
        //this.Refresh();
  }
  // Если нажимаю на кнопку Eng переводим на English язык
  private void SwitchEng_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        SwitchLanguage.Inizialize("en");
        //this.Refresh();
  }
```

Comment: @rudnight "присваивается значение" - для этого обычно используется значок `=`. Повторяю вопрос: сколько раз ...?

Comment: Всё я допёр, спасибо большое за замечание, сразу не понял что нужно так делать. Теперь буду знать) С первым вопросом решили )